# USB does not work

Tags: usb

I recently tried to hook up a keyboard to my Raspberry Pi 2 but it seems like the keyboard was not working. So I tried every other port but still no luck, then I tried I different keyboard still nothing. I then tried using a powered USB hub but it still didn't work. I installed a fresh version raspbian this did nothing. The LAN port works but I have no clue what to do to make the USB ports work.

Comment: Have the USB ports ever worked with anything else? perhaps you have a defective Pi

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are not meeting the power requirements for the Raspberry Pi 2.

The Raspberry Pi Foundation recommends at least 1.8w of power for the Rpi2.

Not having enough power can cause seemingly random behavior like you are describing.

Please see here for details for more details.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/#powerReqs

Comment: This may well be true but how can the OP confirm this. Reading the label on the power supply is no guarantee, nor is simply trying another power supply? What about the cable? Linking to the elinux power issue troubleshooting page would greatly improve your answer.